# How can I save only the time in a sqlite database?

Tags: sqlite

How can I save any time (format: HH:MM:SS) in my sqlite-database?
I don't need the date, only the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite does not have datetime [storage format](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime)
You can use different type of fields to store and functions to read value.

Try to store it as a string with desired format. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Both the `DATE` and the `DATETIME` SQL types are stored in SQLite as the `NUMERIC` type. The `NUMERIC` type is almost identical to an `INTEGER`, apart from the use of CAST. Thus there isn't a great deal of advantage in stripping the date and storing only the time, as an integer say - it won't make a difference to the underlying storage.

Keep storing `DATETIME`, and extract only the time of the day at your presentation layer, to display the time. To be more strict, always set the date to something constant, for example the **epoch** with just the time of the day added to it. Then you can use the `unixepoch` modifier with the [SQLite date functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) when necessary.

For example,

```
SELECT time(1092941466, 'unixepoch', 'localtime');
```

Will compute time given a timestamp of 1092941466 (including the date), compensate for your local timezone, and display only the time of day part:

```
Example output: 04:51:06
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trigger to update your DATETIME field to contain only a Time or a Date. For an example you can create a trigger for insert of table name "logs" to refine the time and date fields like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER "on_insert_logs"  AFTER INSERT ON "logs"

BEGIN 
UPDATE logs SET time = time(time(), 'localtime')  WHERE id = new.id;
UPDATE logs SET date= date(date(), 'localtime')  WHERE id = new.id;

END
```

Comment: To say "contain only Time or a Date" is misleading, `SET time = time(time(), 'localtime')` will still store a full DATETIME in milliseconds from the epoch. To store only the time one would need to store the milliseconds from 00:00:00 in an INTEGER field.